# Spin structure and characteristic classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, finite-groups, characteristic-classes, spin-geometry, cobordism

I do not know if anyone can help me with these doubts of spin structures and characteristic classes.

1) Is there an orientable manifold that is not spin?

2) Is there a finite group $ G $ such that its cohomology ring $ H ^ \ast (BG, \mathbb {Z} / 2) $ is not generated as a ring by the classes $ w_i (E) $ with $ E \rightarrow BG $ ?

Thank you

Comment: The answer to 1) is "Yes", one family of examples is $\mathbb{C}P^{2k}$ (you can find the formula for the Chern classes of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ in Milnor-Stasheff theorem 14.10, then apply problem 14B to compute Stiefel-Whitney classes).

Comment: For 2), what exactly do you mean by "$w_i(E)$ with $E\to BG$"? Are you asking wether $H^*(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is generated by the classes $w_i(E)$ as $E$ ranges over all real vector bundles over $BG$?